# How do I add to the default permissions of a model in Django

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have my user

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
```

I want to add a default permission to this class in addition to the default ones provided by django

```
add: user.has_perm('foo.add_user')
change: user.has_perm('foo.change_user')
delete: user.has_perm('foo.delete_user')
```

how do I go about this

will this overite the default?

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # model stuff here
    class Meta:
        permissions = ( 
            ( "extra_user", "Can do extra" ),
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two options with this issue, which belong to the common question on how to extend the User model.

The first option is to completely substitute the User model with a custom one, which will contain any custom permissions too. This is described thoroughly in the relevant [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

The second option is to extend the current user model with a custom model that contains an one-to-one field with auth.User. The new model will contain any custom permissions, and you would need to check against those. This is too described in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

If one does not mind (design-wise) the fact that the custom permissions belong to a separate model from the default Django User model, then the second option is slightly easier to code and maintain.

Comment: i want to apply a mixin to all my models to add the extra permissions, in option 1 , what is the syntax for specigying permissions, do i do it in the meta?

Comment: Yes, you do it as you would in any custom model.

Comment: @MrMixin, I should have guessed that you would want to apply a mixin to all your models!